# How to capture webcam image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I run this code flash is open but when I click on snap button it only shows uploading message instead of showing capture image.

**My view:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .img {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }

    .shiva {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        background: #2A49A5;
        border: 1px solid #082783;
        box-shadow: 0 1px #4C6BC7 inset;
        color: white;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #082783;
        font: 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<html>

<body style="background-color:#dfe3ee;">
    <div id="outer" style="margin:0px; width:100%; height:90px;background-color:#3B5998;">
    </div>
    <div id="main" style="height:800px; width:100%">
        <div id="content" style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:50px; margin-top:20px;" align="center">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/cam/webcam.js"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                document.write(webcam.get_html(440, 240));
            </script>
            <form>
                <br />
                <input type=button value="Configure settings" onClick="webcam.configure()" class="shiva"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=button value="snap" onClick="take_snapshot()" class="shiva">
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            webcam.set_api_url('<?php echo base_url();?>camera/saveImage');
            webcam.set_quality(90);
            webcam.set_shutter_sound(true);
            webcam.set_hook('onComplete', 'my_completion_handler');

            function take_snapshot() {
                document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading...</h1>';
                webcam.snap();
            }

            function my_completion_handler(msg) {
                if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
                    document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '<h3>Upload Successfuly done</h3>' + msg;

                    document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = "<img src=" + msg + " class=\"img\">";
                    webcam.reset();
                } else {
                    alert("Error occured we are trying to fix now: " + msg);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <div id="img" style=" height:800px; width:500px; float:left; margin-left:40px; margin-top:20px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**My controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Camera extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view("camera");

        }


        public function saveImage(){

            /*write your own code to save to your database*/        
            $newname = "some_name.png";
            $filepath = "assets/images/";
            file_put_contents( $newname . $filepath, file_get_contents('php://input') );

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why use flash? For example: http://tutsheap.com/web/javascript/take-still-photos-webcam-using-javascript/ and send 'data' to the backend.